# How can I display the 2 images and and their names horizontally?

Tags: php, html, css

This is main problem of my system I can display images and their names but it cant't be a horizontal.. Need help please[image: Here's an example pic]. Cause when I run my codes the images will be vertically but I want to be in a horizontal

Here;s the code:

```
echo'<?php $src=array("candidates/images/".$rows["image"]); for($i=0;$i<2;$i++){ ?>';

                            echo '<div clas ="image">';
                                        echo '<img src="candidates/images/'.$rows['image'].'" width="10" height="20px" />'.',&nbsp;'.'<br>'.$rows['lastname'].',&nbsp;'.$rows['firstname'].'<br>'.'&nbsp;=&nbsp;'.$rows['votes'];


                                        //  echo '<br>';
                                        }

                                            $sdsd=$dsada    
                                        ?>
                                    <img  src="candidates/images/percent.gif"width='<?php echo(100*round($rows['votes']/($sdsd),2)); ?>'height='10'>
                                <?php 
                                if ($rows['votes']==0){
                                echo "<br>";}
                                else {
                            //  echo(100*round($rows['votes']/($sdsd),2)); /
                            /*?>%<br>*/
    /*<?php
                            }
                            */echo '</div>';
                        }
                        }
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.image {
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-bloxk;
}
```

Comment: Could you draw how you would like them horizontal? Confused what u want with the text. 
Please note: it's inline-block, not inline-bloxk. Also in your HTML, it should be 'class=' instead of 'clas ='
Aditionally, I would suggest adding in float: left; in your CSS

Comment: tnx for the observation and I follow what you have written but nothings, happen

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<br>` ?

echo ''.', '.'
'.$rows['lastname'].', '.$rows['firstname'].'
'.' = '.$rows['votes'];